# What can we say when $[A,B]=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, operator-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{C}_{n\times n}$ and let $[A,B]$ be their commutator. What can we say when
$$
[A,B]=A \quad ?
$$
It feels like this is something interesting to study (specially in physics). Does anyone know of any resources on this?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2652054/446262)

Comment: Is this the commutator $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$, or is it the commutator $AB-BA$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson if this has anything to do with physics, then $[A,B] = AB-BA$. This is sort of canonical among physicists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223496/example-of-two-dimensional-non-abelian-lie-algebra)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $A$ and $AB-BA$ commute, show that $AB-BA$ is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227984/if-a-and-ab-ba-commute-show-that-ab-ba-is-nilpotent)

Answer (score 2):

If ${\cal A}$ is a complex Banach algebra the following is known (Bonsall, Duncan: *Complete Normed Algebras*, §18 Prop. 13): Let $a,b \in {\cal A}$ and
$a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)a$. Then $r(ab-ba) =0$ (here $r$ denotes the spectral radius). Hence in the case $[A,B]=A$ we have $A[A,B]=A^2=[A,B]A$ and get $r(AB-BA)=r(A)=0$. Thus $A$ is a nilpotent matrix.

Edit: As $A$ is nilpotent I wondered whether $A=0$ at least if $n$ is small, but no $(n=2)$: Let
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right), \quad
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta \\
0 & 1+\alpha
\end{array} \right).
$$
Then $[A,B]=A$.

Comment: Why do you need $a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)a$?

Comment: This is the assumption in the Proposition used. At least you need something to conclude that $r(AB-BA)=0$ since that is false, in general.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

$$[A,B]=A \implies \\
e^{-B} A e^B= A + A + A/2!+ A/3!+... = (1+e)A.$$

You are dealing with the [affine group in one dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group#Matrix_representation), whose Lie algebra is the simplest 2d nonabelian Lie algebra.